# Select2, need to group results into one for display

Tags: grouping, jquery-select2-4

I use "multiple select boxes" ([select2 examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)) and I want to group showing results: 
[image]

like (only if selected more then X options):

[image]

Whithout this the field with the results will be too large. Also, I don't want to make a scroll in the field results.

Is there any ready solution to do this?

Comment: Now I'm trying to do templateSelection function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test").select2();
});
function select_grouping(obj) {
  var min_grouping_count = 3;
  var title = ' elements selected';
  var count = 0;
  if (obj.children('li').length > min_grouping_count) {
    if (obj.children('li').length > min_grouping_count) {
      count = obj.children('li').length - 1;
      obj.children('li').each(function(index, el) {
        if (index > 0 && index < count) {
          $(this).remove();
        }
      });
    }
    obj.children('li:eq(0)').html(count + title);
  }
}
$(".test").on("select2:select", function(obj) {
  var obj = $('#filtr_test').find('.select2-selection__rendered');
  select_grouping(obj);
});
$(".test").on("select2:unselect", function(obj) {
  var obj = $('#filtr_test').find('.select2-selection__rendered');
  select_grouping(obj);
});
```

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="filtr_test">
  <select class="test" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
    <option value="5">five</option>
    <option value="6">six</option>
    <option value="7">seven</option>
  </select>
</div>
```